# Article before "possible WHO pre-qualification of the vaccine"

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

I am having a bit of hard time pondering over why there is not an article before "Possible who pre-qualification of the vaccine" in the following sentence:

> We are in close contact with Russian health authorities and discussions are ongoing with respect to possible WHO prequalification of the vaccine.

This excerpt has been taken from "The Economic Times" newspaper.

Comment: Are you aware of what WHO stands for in this context?

Comment: @cjl750 Yes, its World health organization.

Comment: But as it is, it sounds OK without any article - definite or indefinite.

Comment: @RamPillai ok. Thanks for replying. But shouldn't there be any article before "pre-qualification" since there is only "one" pre-qualification is going to be done? And hence, a distinct one? May be definite as well?

Comment: Here, 'possible WHO pre-qualification' is an NP used in a general way. Hence, it is fine without an article. If it was something like, ...unavoidable WHO pre-qualification... we could use an article due to the nature of emphasis.

Comment: @RamPillai I assumed "pre-qualification" was something unavoidable like " the only WHO pre-qualification that's going to be taking place" and hence I thought of using an article before it. Now I can see where I made a mistake. Thanks.